# Search + replace mySQL data

Tags: php, mysql

Our forum is based on phpbb3 and for sometime we have been using a syntax highlight mod. We've decided to drop the mod and return to the basic bbcode tags. Long story short - I need to update mySQL fields (phpbb_forum_posts, post_text) that contain:

```
Text Text Text Text Text 
[swordfish filename=code.bas]
code code code
123
code code[/swordfish]
Text Text Text Text Text
```

To

```
Text Text Text Text Text 
[code]
code code code
123
code code[/code]
Text Text Text Text Text
```

It is worth highlighting that `[swordfish filename=code.bas]` could contain other fields such as `[swordfish filename=code.bas abc 123]`. Regardless of what's in the first tag, it needs to be changed to `[code]`

This is a bit out of my "need to know" scope, and I would really appreciate if someone could help design either a mySQL or PHP script to achieve a mass update. (I know my way around the basics, not enough for advanced search/replace)

Comment: Are these all in one table in one column, or code it exist across multiple tables and multiple columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$regexp = '/\[(\/)?swordfish[^\]]*\]/';

$push = 'REPLACE whatever_table (id, post_text)
          VALUES';

$pull = 'SELECT id, post_text
           FROM whatever_table
          WHERE whatever = condition';

if ( $result = $mysqli->query($pull) ) {
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $row['post_text'] = preg_replace($regexp, '[$1code]', $row['post_text']);

        $push .= sprintf(
            ' ("%s", "%s"),',
            $mysqli->real_escape_string($row['id']),
            $mysqli->real_escape_string($row['post_text'])
        );
    }

    $result->free();
}

$mysqli->query(rtrim($push, ','));
```

**EDIT**
Please note that the `REPLACE` statement is NOT complete! You would have to fetch every column and write it back (not just the two I mentioned).